Querying KDB+ Server Using Python
I'm trying to process data that is stored on KDB+ server using Jupyter notebook.
This is how I connected to the server:
connection = kx.QConnection(host='localhost', port=5000)

Then O read a csv file using:
table1 = connection.read.csv("path/to/file", schema)

After that, I wrote the table1 to the database:
connection('insert', 'table1', conn_table1)

I need to implement the following which is not working:
start_date="3/6/2015 12:44:31"
end_date="3/6/2020 12:44:31"
connection(f'select col1 datetimecol2 by col1 from table1 where col3<`2  & datetimecol2 within (`${start_date};`${end_date})')

How can I do it using KDB+? And where can I find a good resource to learn KDB+?
Thank you!
I expected to get some results but instead I got an error: QError: /

Your query builds to:
select col1 datetimecol2 by col1 from table1 
     where col3<`2  & datetimecol2 within (`$3/6/2015 12:44:31;`$3/6/2020 12:44:31)

The issues:

You do not have a , between the column names col1 datetimecol2, this would cause datetimecol2 to attempt to be used to index in to col1 and is not what you intended to do I am guessing. If datetimecol2 is a symbol type this operation would fail with type
You have col1 to the left and right of by, this is not allowed and would error with 'dup names for cols/groups col1
You are attempting to create symbols with special characters in them (  and /). These must be wrapped in ""
You are using col3<`2 doing a less than operation on a symbol datatype. While this can technically work it's more likely you want a numeric column and comparison
In a where clause you don't use & by default. A , separates where clauses

Implementing fixes 1-5 gives a workable query:
select datetimecol2 by col1 from table1 
     where col3<2, datetimecol2 within (`$"3/6/2015 12:44:31";`$"3/6/2020 12:44:31")


You are using the symbol datatype for timestamps, this is inefficient

Your timestamp format can be parsed by q:
q)"P"$"3/6/2015 12:44:31"
2015.03.06D12:44:31.000000000

So in your schema you should use more similar to:
schema = {'col3':kx.LongAtom,
          'datetimecol2':kx.TimestampAtom,
           }

Then your query should pass parameters and not build up complex strings:
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime.strptime("3/6/2015 12:44:31",'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
end_date=datetime.strptime("3/6/2020 12:44:31",'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

connection('{select datetimecol2 by col1 from table1 where
                            col3<2, datetimecol2 within (x;y)}',
              start_date, end_date)

See:

https://code.kx.com/pykx/2.5/user-guide/fundamentals/text.html
https://code.kx.com/q/basics/datatypes/

The KX Academy has courses you can follow to learn q/kdb+ and PyKX
https://learninghub.kx.com/academy/

It worked thank you! I noticed that `timesstamp$datatime1 executes faster than "P"$"datetime1". Is that right?

No, that is cast, you want tok to parse the string.

Sorry I checked cast and tok but did not get the difference. Would you explain them more for me please?

"I"$"10" is tok and will parse the string. Output 10i. \int$"10"iscastand **casts** the data. Output49 48ibecause it casts each character individually. The numbers49and48and the underlying ASCII values for"1"and"0"` https://www.asciitable.com/

Test on q)\timestamp$"3/6/2015 12:44:31" you will see output2000.01.01D00:00:00.000000051 2000.01.01D00:00:00.000000047 2000.01.01D00:00:00.000000054 2000.01.01D00:00:00.000000047 2000.01.01D00:00:00.000000050 2000.01.01D00:0..as it tries to cast each character to a timestamp individually. It's not what you want. "P"$"3/6/2015 12:44:31"parses it to a correct timestamp2015.03.06D12:44:31.000000000`

Got it! Thank you appreciate it!

With the query you're attempting to run there are a couple of changes which should unblock the query specifically.
The Error that q is raising in this case specifically is related to the / in your datetime objects, in order to resolve this you could pass them through as q formatted strings or probably more usefully pass the datetimes in directly. PyKX will convert them from the datetime representation to their PyKX equivalent.
from datetime import datetime
start_date=datetime.strptime("03/6/2015 12:44:31", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
end_date=datetime.strptime("03/6/2020 12:44:31", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

connection('{select datetimecol2 by col1 from table1 where col3<2, datetimecol2 within (x;y)}', start_date, end_date)

With regards to resources on the q side, the q-for-mortals book available at https://code.kx.com/q4m3/ is a great resource to get started on all elements of q, in your case for this example the q-sql section here may be of interest

Thank you! Apparently, KDB+ accepts dates separated by point not slash so I have to do some restructuring to the code but eventually it worked thank you!
